# Can I pass variable in the browser.find_element_by_link_text() in selenium - python?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Say for example I have this list of keywords: "**Head,Feet, Hand,Fingers**"
How can I pass all of these inside "**()**" of **browser.find_element_by_link_text()**?
Purpose is to search all these keywords one by one and if found, will simulate clicking through each of the keyword.

sample code:

```
for i in browser.find_element_by_link_text("**all keywords should be passed here**"):
        i.click()
```

PS. Python Newbie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot pass multiple link texts to `find_element_by_link_text()`.

You have multiple ways to approach the problem. You can, for instance, switch to using *XPath locators* - dynamically construct an expression checking all the link text variations:

```
link_texts = ["Head", "Feet", "Hand", "Fingers"]
expression = "//a[%s]" % (" or ".join(". = '%s'" % link_text for link_text in link_texts))

for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(expression):
    link.click()
```

Or, you can issue `find_element_by_link_text()` in a loop handling [`NoSuchElementException` exception](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException) (in case an element is not found) properly:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

link_texts = ["Head", "Feet", "Hand", "Fingers"]
for link_text in link_texts:
    try:
        link = driver.find_element_by_link_text(link_text)
        link.click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("Link text '%s' not found" % link_text)
```

The latter option would be slower, but at the same time much more explicit.

Comment: the 2nd suggestion results to "NameError: name 'NoSuchElementException' is not defined"...I'll  figure the first one tomorrow, I can't make it work..Thanks mate

Comment: @CuriousCat yeah, you need to import it, added to the answer. Hope that helps.